# how to insert php function to array

Tags: php, arrays

this is my curl array

```
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://xxxxxx.com/v2/transaction?ref_id=[ref_id]',
```

and i need to change [ref_id] to $result['useridInvoice']
what is the best url to solve this problem

help me please to solve my problem

Comment: Something like [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)?

Answer (score 0):

$result['useridInvoice'] to create the final URL.

For example, you can use the following line of code to create the final URL:

```
$url = 'https://xxxxxx.com/v2/transaction?ref_id=' . $result['useridInvoice'];
```

Then you can set the value of CURLOPT_URL to this variable:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
```

You can also use the sprintf function to format the URL string and enter the value of$result['useridInvoice']:

```
$url = sprintf('https://xxxxxx.com/v2/transaction?ref_id=%s', $result['useridInvoice']);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
```

Both of these methods will replace the [ref_id] placeholder in the URL with the value of $result['useridInvoice'], resulting in the desired final URL.